# How to use gensim for lda on news articles?

Tags: machine-learning, lda, gensim

I'm trying to retrieve list of topics from a large corpus of news articles, I'm planning to use gensim to extract a topic distribution for each document using LDA. I want to know the format of processed articles required by gensim implementation of lda and how to convert raw articles to that format. I saw this link about using lda on wikipedia dump but I found the corpus to be in a processed state whose format was not mentioned anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an offline learning step and an online feature creation step.

**Offline Learning**

Assume you have a big corpus such as Wikipedia or downloaded a bunch of news articles.

For each article/document:

1. You get the raw text
2. You lemmatize it. Gensim has utils.lemmatize
3. You create a dictionary
4. You create a bag of word representation

Then you train the TF-IDF model and convert the whole corpus to the TF-IDF space.
Finally, you train the LDA model on the "TF-IDF corpus".

**Online**

With an incoming news article you do almost the same:

1. Lemmatize it
2. Create a bag of word representaiton using the dictionary.
3. Convert it to TF-IDF space using the TF-IDF model
4. Convert it to LDA space.

Comment: Can you say, how to convert from lda space back to normal, I can`t understand.

Comment: Do mean you have the distribution of topics over a document and want to have the document in TF-IDF space?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if I got the problem right, but gensim supports multiple corpora. You can find a list of them [here](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/apiref.html).

If you want to  process natural language, you have to tokenize the text first. You can follow the step-by-step tutorial on the gensim website [here](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/tutorial.html). It's explained pretty well.